# Haskell/Aseon: output JSON as one object

Tags: haskell, ghc, aeson

I have the following Haskell code which encodes a list of the data type `User` in JSON and prints it to the standard output:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

module Main where

import Data.Aeson
import Data.Text
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as B

data User = User
    { id :: String
    , name :: String
    , address :: String
    } deriving (Show)

instance ToJSON User where
    toJSON (User id name address) = object
        [ pack id .= object
            [ "name" .= name
            , "address" .= address
            ]
        ]

users :: [User]
users = [ User "user 1" "name of user 1" "address of user 1"
        , User "user 2" "name of user 2" "address of user 2"
        ] 

main :: IO ()
main = B.putStrLn $ encode users
```

At the moment, the code produces the following output:

```
[
  {
    "user 1": {
      "address": "address of user 1",
      "name": "name of user 1"
    }
  },
  {
    "user 2": {
      "address": "address of user 2",
      "name": "name of user 2"
    }
  }
]
```

However, I would like to output the following JSON structure (joining the inner two objects):

```
{
  "user 1": {
    "name": "name of user 1",
    "address": "address of user 1"
  },
  "user 2": {
    "name": "name of user 2",
    "address": "address of user 2"
  }
}
```

How will I have to change `toJSON` in order to print the desired encoded JSON?

Comment: Not too fluent in haskell but can you get rid of the outer object wrapping the inner object?

Comment: Not really, because I can't just get rid of the outer object since there are two inner objects and not just one. The inner ones will first have to be merged first.

Comment: Is there a typo in the queston?  I see `"lastname": "name of user 2"` in the desired output but `"lastname"` does not show up anywhere else in the question.

Comment: @DaveCompton, yes, sorry, I have now corrected the typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How will I have to change toJSON in order to print the desired encoded JSON?

There is nothing you can do to change `toJSON` for `User` to print desired encoded JSON. Problem is not in `User` encoding but in list encoding. Simple list just encoded as JSON array. And JSON array doesn't have values (so you can't have `["user 1":{...}]` thus each object is wrapped into `{}`). This problem can be solved in different ways. One of the easiest solution is to write custom encoder for list of `User`. Here how it looks like:

```
import qualified Data.HashMap.Strict as HM

usersEncode :: [User] -> Object
usersEncode = HM.unions . map (\(Object user) -> user) . map toJSON
```

Adn then in `main` you can call it like this:

```
main = B.putStrLn $ encode $ usersEncode users
```

And it gives you desired output.

The trick is in the fact that `aeson` stores objects as `HashMap` from `Text` to `Value`. And `HashMap` is encoded as JSON object. So the idea of given solution is to convert each user to singleton `HashMap` and then unite all `HashMap`s.

**Note**: it will remove users with duplicated `userId` from list.